# Nesting structures JSON style in C++

Tags: c++, json, visual-c++, struct

I am trying to explicitly initialize a nested `struct` but I cannot find any fault in my code. I am using Visual Studio 2013 with Visual C++ compiler. When trying to compile the code below I get the following error message: "An internal error has occurred in the compiler."

```
    // Parameter determines which menu will be displayed (0, 1, or 2).
    int menu(int n) {

        struct Menus_obj {
            struct Menu_obj {
                string query;
                string choices[5];
            };
            Menu_obj Menu;
        };

        Menus_obj Menus[3] = {
            {
                "Fruit type (1-5): ",
                {
                    "1. Apple - 1.00\n",
                    "2. Orange - 2.00\n",
                    "3. Banana - 3.00\n",
                    "4. Blueberry - 5.00\n",
                    "5. Blackberry - 8.00\n"
                }
            },
            {
                "Vegetable type (1-5): ",
                {
                    "1. Broccoli - 2.00\n",
                    "2. Spinach - 4.00\n",
                    "3. Kale - 6.00\n",
                    "4. Cauliflower - 8.00\n",
                    "5. Moringa - 10.00\n"
                }
            },
            {
                "Number of shoppers: ",
                {
                    "",
                    "",
                    "",
                    "",
                    ""
                }
            }
        };

        cout << Menus[n].Menu.query << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            cout << Menus[n].Menu.choices[i];
        }

        cin >> n;
        return n - 1;

    }
```

Is there fault in my code, and / or is it a logical error; am I trying to do something incorrectly? Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's no problem with your struct definition. The fault in your code is probably a runtime undefined behavior and a crash, since you're probably accessing array outside its bound (`n` is not range-checked). Here's a runnable example: http://ideone.com/l3MVtB

Comment: @DmitryLedentsov if you see the comment above, n is conditioned only to be 0, 1, or 2. As you can see there are only three nested `structs`. The problem turned out to be a container glitch where `strings` and `string arrays` are not accepted as sibling nodes from within an array of `structs`. See Andy's hack below.

Comment: Such code may not obey the `OPC` . You better don't do your code like this. `not easy to extend but easy to modify.`

Comment: no hack needed, see the runnable code in my link.

Comment: @AntiMoron Could you please elaborate? I know this isn't typical C++ style. What would be a better way to write this?

Comment: @DmitryLedentsov Thanks for your contribution. Looking at your code, I now see that your first comment is actually accurate because I need to traverse in a nested statement, wrapped with a traversal pointing to the parent container.. right? Could you please submit your code as an answer with additional information with further elaboration? Also, could you please also explain your usage of the menu pointer of type auto? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Jim22150, [range-based for](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) + [auto](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's always fun to find an internal compiler error. Firstly you should submit your test code to MS so they can fix the issue.

Secondly, since the issue is with the initialisation of the `string` objects in the array within the `struct` we just need to put them into an anonymous `struct` to achieve a workaround.

Change your `Menus_obj` structure to look like this and it'll compile fine.

```
struct Menus_obj {
  struct Menu_obj {
    string query;             
    struct { 
      string choices[5]; 
    };
  };
  Menu_obj Menu;
};
```

Comment: thanks a lot, that did the trick. I actually thought about doing that. Nice hack, thanks again!

Comment: where's the member declaration of the anonymous struct?